# How to save to file?

Tags: c, printf

I've got a problem with my project. I don't know how to add an option which will save to file the result's from console. I think i shoud use `fprintf` but nothing works. Please help  ;D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct symbole
{
    int symbol;
    int czestosc;
};

struct symbole nowy[256];

void odczytIwyznaczenie(void);
void wyswietl(struct symbole nowy[]);
void sortuj(struct symbole nowy[]);

int main()
{
    odczytIwyznaczenie();
    sortuj(nowy);
    wyswietl(nowy);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


void odczytIwyznaczenie (void)
{

    FILE *plik;
    char n;
    int i;


    for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        nowy[i].czestosc=0;
        nowy[i].symbol=i;
    }

    plik = fopen("plik.txt","r");
    if (plik == NULL)
    {
        printf("Blad odczytu!");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    while (n != EOF)
    {
        n = fgetc(plik);

        for(i=0; i<256; i++)
        {
            if (nowy[i].symbol == n)
            {
                nowy[i].czestosc++;
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    fclose (plik);
}


void sortuj(struct symbole nowy[])
{
    int i, j, temp, temp1;

    for (i = (256); i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (nowy[j-1].czestosc < nowy[j].czestosc)
            {
                temp = nowy[j-1].czestosc;
                temp1=nowy[j-1].symbol;
                nowy[j-1].czestosc = nowy[j].czestosc;
                nowy[j-1].symbol=nowy[j].symbol;
                nowy[j].czestosc = temp;
                nowy[j].symbol=temp1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void wyswietl(struct symbole nowy[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        if (nowy[i].czestosc!= 0)
            printf ("%5d| %5c| %5d\n", nowy[i].symbol, nowy[i].symbol, nowy[i].czestosc);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a severe error, `n` is not initialized before `while (n != EOF)` suggest `while ((n = fgetc(plik)) != EOF)`.

Comment: And please use english to name your identifiers, I am not a native english speaker, but it's better when one can guess what a function does or what an identifier defines from the function or identifier name, and since english is the universal language of programming, well english it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed need `fprintf()`, use it as follows

```
void wyswietl(struct symbole nowy[])
{
    FILE *output;
    int   i;

    output = fopen("OuptputFile.txt", "w");
    if (output == NULL) /* maybe you don't have permission to create the file */
        return;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++)
    {
        if (nowy[i].czestosc == 0)
            continue;
        fprintf(output, "%5d| %5c| %5d\n", nowy[i].symbol, 
            nowy[i].symbol, nowy[i].czestosc);
    }
}
```

Also, you have to initialize `n` before comparing it to `EOF`, change

```
while (n != EOF)
```

which is reached before `n` is initialized, to

```
while ((n = fgetc(pilk)) != EOF)
```

Comment: thanks, cool, but results are different. I have to count and sort signs from mu input file. Now i've got as a result ascii table without signs from my file.